# Birth Record Missing: Joseph C. (POLEO) O'BRIEN 1921 - 1981

Tags: united-states, dna, birth-records, new-york-state

My project invlolves finding the proof of birth for:
Joseph C. (POLEO) O'BRIEN (born, orphaned, adopted?)
Apparent info (not certain) is:
BIRTH 05 JUN 1921 • Brooklyn, Kings, New York, USA
DEATH 11 OCT 1981 • Monroe, Orange, New York, USA

This is taken from SS Death Index.

His daughter's DNA leads to a 223 cM match with roots to surname O'Brien.

We believe his parents are Joseph A Poleo and Agnes O'Brien - but cannot find evidence of this and the NYC Birth Index does not have a matching entry.

Need a birth cert - death cert leads nowhere certain since informant did not have this data.

---

**Moderator's note on Privacy Policy**:

Joseph was born less than 100 years ago but evidence of his decease can be found at:

> "United States Social Security Death Index," database, FamilySearch
>   (https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:JKKP-PNY : 20 May 2014),
>   Joseph Obrien, Oct 1981; citing U.S. Social Security Administration,
>   Death Master File, database (Alexandria, Virginia: National Technical
>   Information Service, ongoing).

Comment: Which NYC Birth Index are you referring to?  The published index ends in 1909, so wouldn't include a 1921 birth.

Comment: I am referring to the "New York, New York, Birth Index, 1910-1965" that has been available for some time now - albeit without parent information.

Comment: Moderator's edit is superfluous as my original post indicated the SS Death Index was the source of my data!

Comment: I think a link to evidence is better than just mentioning it. With just a mention I had to go looking for it, whereas the link enables other potential answerers to save volunteering that time.